# how I can do mouse click in cypress

Tags: cypress

I have a scenario where only mouse click will work and I have to click with only mouse. .click method actually not working there and even I try with {force: true} everything. Is there any way I can simulate the Mouse action in cypress ?

Comment: Can you show us your code and the HTML (the element you are trying to click) That would be very helpful.

Comment: sure, Well I try a lot but the element actually hidden and even with force:true its able to click but the picker value did not change at all. Im automating M UI  calendar component 

here is execution screenshot. https://ibb.co/x53SrW8